# Compare objects by multiple fields in Java - dict method in Python

Tags: java, python

In python we can compare object by attributes by this method:

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

It allows us to compare objects by their attributes no matter how many attributes they have.

Is something like this possible in Java?
I tried to compare objects in this way, but you have to compare them by every attribute. Is it possible to do it similarly to Python **eq** method above?

```
public class MyClass {

public MyClass(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) {
    this.attr1 = attr1;
    this.attr2 = attr2;
    this.attr3 = attr3;
    this.attr4 = attr4;
}
public boolean equals(Object object2) {

    return object2 instanceof MyClass && 
attr1.equals(((MyClass)object2).attr1)&&......;
}
}
```

Comment: If hardcoding is not an option, it might make sense to store your attributes in a hashmap. I believe those util classes have methods to perform element wise comparisons...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: Err... never mind. Apex (very similar to Java) hashmaps do have this feature, [java hashmaps don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082416/equality-between-2-hashmap).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write general method that handles every type, you need to use reflection. If you just want to do this with a type or two, then I suggest you override the `equals` method for each individual type i.e. hardcoding it.

Here's how you write a generic method that accepts every single type and compares the fields for equality:

```
private static <T> boolean allFieldsEqual(T a, T b) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = a.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (!field.get(a).equals(field.get(b))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The logic is pretty self-explanatory. Here is the usage:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Tom", 1);
Student s2 = new Student("Tom", 1);
try {
    System.out.println(allFieldsEqual(s1, s2));
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`Student` is defined as:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```